# Configuring Application Gateway with API management Azure

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

I want to establish an connection between API managment and Application Gateway in Azure.
Please can someone provide step by step solution.

Answer (score 4):

What is your scenario? Generally, people set up API Management in an internal VNET and expose a small set of APIs via Application Gateway with a [WAF SKU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/waf-overview), which is an extra Web application firewall for Front.

Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway

Comment: My requirement is Application Gateway is under separate NSG and Application Management is under separate NSG but both are in same VNET. 
Application Gateway is in a subnet and API Management is in own subnet.
Application Gateway should send traffic to API Management.

Comment: We have Application Gateway in a subnet w/o NSG - the WAF here is protection enough. But from AppGw-Subnet to APIM-Subnet we only allow inbound 443.